# jquery loading in a rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that uses jquery and jqueryUI.

I use some jqueryUI styling elements. The problem is that when I get a few entries in my database the page takes some time to load. Because the jqueryUI elements are implemented after the document ready function, I see the unstyled page for a fraction of a second.

What can I do to display the right styling while the page is loading? Is it possible or do I have to display a spinner? If so how can I display the spinner with unobtrusive javascript?